# System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007203B): A local error has occurred

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

When we try to search for a user in ActiveDirectory, we get that exception - `0x8007203B`.

Basically we deployed a web service, which uses `DirectoryEntry` & `DirectorySearcher` class to find a user in AD, and sometimes this exception happens. But when we do IISReset, it again works fine.

Code is very simple like this:

```
DirectoryEntry domainUser = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xxx.yyy/dc=xxx,dc=yyy", "domain\user", "pwd", AuthenticationTypes.Secure); 
DirectoryEntry result = new DirectorySearcher(domainUser, filter);
```

Only some times this happens. I don't have much information to provide, any guess much appreciated

This is how my filter looks like

```
public static string BuildFilter(DirectoryEntry dirEntry, string userName, string userMail)
{
   try
   {
      string filter = string.Empty;

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(userMail))
         filter = string.Format(@"(&(objectClass=user)(samaccounttype=805306368)(|(CN={0})(samaccountname={0})))", userName);
      else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userMail))
         filter = string.Format(@"(&(objectClass=user)(samaccounttype=805306368)(mail={0}))", userMail);
      else
         filter = string.Format(@"(&(objectClass=user)(samaccounttype=805306368)(|(CN={0})(samaccountname={0})(mail={1})))", userName, userMail);

      return filter;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       _logger.Error("BuildUserSearch - Failed to build LDAP search", ex);
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you do to set up your `DirectorySearcher` !! What does your `filter` look like?? What other options are you setting??

Comment: @marc_s, i have added the filter code, and i don't have access to their security logs, but as i mentioned it works, but fails sometimes continuously. But IISReset makes it works again.

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you on?? There are two things you could try: (1) use the `anr=` search parameter in your filter, or (2) move to the new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace (requires .NET 3.5 or up) which is much easier to use for searching - not sure if it'll fix the error, though :-(

Comment: @marc_s, thanks. i will try AccountManagement

Answer (score 0):

You say that this it's just append after some time. As DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher are built on COM object into disposable class I would first just add some `using` sections to be sure that underlying objects are corectly freed.

```
using(DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath))
{
  using(DirectorySearcher searcher=new DirectorySearcher(root))
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, dispose was missing in my code, i will add it now, hope this was the cause.

Answer (score -2):

Any guess are appreciated?

Then here's mine:

1. [ASP.NET: DirectoryServicesCOMException [...]](http://forums.asp.net/t/1517772.aspx);
2. [Windows Error Codes: Repair 0x8007203B. How To Repair 0x8007203B](http://www.cedhost.com/repair-0x8007203b-how-to-repair-0x8007203b.php).

What makes me confuse is that you say it works most of the time...

Did this help?

P.S. I'll update if I think of anything else.

Comment: Is the cedhost.com link really any use? Aren't they one of the sites that throw up pages for every error code to sell registry cleaner software? Why does the page say I have that error?!